# FoxPro 9.0 pop-ups

Tags: foxpro

For some reason my FoxPro program decide to return pop ups while the program is running. It shows tables that are used in the program. This appears without consistency in the code, is this a generic feature? I really want it to stop.

Answer (score 3):

I would think that the "popup" is actually prompting you to pick the name of a table that is not already open and is asking you "hey... which table do you want to use".

I can only presume this from following your other crazy thread trying to keep adding columns to a pre-existing table result set.  You might be confusing it with table names / temp table names during your process.

REVISED PER FEEDBACK

Then what I am suspecting is you are getting that as a result of a query without an INTO clause putting in into a temp table or cursor.  If you just run a query WITHOUT that, it just shows the results immediately.

Ex:

```
select * from SomeTable where SomeCondition
```

will result in showing the "table" results.

However,

```
select * from SomeTable where SomeCondition INTO TABLE SomeTempTable
or
select * from SomeTable where SomeCondition INTO CURSOR SomeTempAliasName
```

will query and put the results in the respective result temp table or cursor

Comment: Hi, as I write in my question the pop up is of a table. Not a "choose file" pop up. So what I see on my screen is a table and nothing else.

Comment: @Orongo, see revised answer

Comment: Just to add to DRapp's comment, one place you can run into this issue is if you have combos or listboxes with RowSourceType=3-Query. Make sure those queries include INTO clauses.

Answer (score 0):

> I really want it to stop.

One thing to take into consideration is that the program only pops up a windows like you describe when it cannot find something that is essential to it running.

Rather than simplisticly wanting the pop-ups to go away, you should be looking for the reason that they are appearing in the first place.

Then, once those reasons are resolved, the pop-ups will no longer appear.

Good Luck